# 32bit wav file metadata

Tags: c#, audio, wav

I am trying to write a sin wave to a stereo 32-bit wav file. I assume that the value can be between -2147483647 and +2147483647 which is probably wrong because I dont get the required result.

```
//I add 8 to i because it is a stereo wav file and this way I'am able to modify only the left channel (or right)
for (int i = 0; i < capturedAudioBuffer.BytesRecorded; i=i+8)
{

    //sin function gives a result between -1 and 1 therefore I convert it into the required range.
    int sinval = (int)(2147483646 * ((System.Math.Sin(((i/8) / 180.0f) *             (double)System.Math.PI))));
    byte[] b1 = new byte[4];
    b1 = convertToByte(sinval);
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i + 3] = b1[0];
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i + 2] = b1[1];
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i + 1] = b1[2];
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i] = b1[3];
}
```

I created a sin wave with a program and it seems that the max value is BF 80 00 00 and the min value is 3F 80 00 00 so it confused me a little. I couldn't find anything about the actual data but the header of the file. So can somebody describe me what is happening here?

Solution (Thanks for Roman R.):

```
    float sinval = (float)(((System.Math.Sin(((i/8) / 180.0f) * (double)System.Math.PI))));
    b1 = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(sinval);
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i + 3] = b1[3];
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i + 2] = b1[2];
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i + 1] = b1[1];
    capturedAudioBuffer.Buffer[i] = b1[0];
```

Comment: How do you write the wav header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit PCM format can also be using (and perhaps even more frequent) single precision floating point values, in range `-1.0..1.0`.

The header would have to specify this as `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT`, see [Extensible Wave-Format Descriptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.